# how to have a python script save data

Tags: python, apache-kafka

currently I have a python script that takes data from an object and modifies it, then produces it to a kafka topic, it looks something like this (without the logic functions):

```
def produce_data(data):
    record_value = json.dumps(data)
    print("Producing record: {}\t{}".format("timeseries data", record_value))
    time.sleep(0)
    producer.produce(topic, key="timeseries data", value=record_value, on_delivery=ack)
    producer.poll(0)
    producer.flush()
    print("{} messages were produced to topic {}!".format(delivered_records, topic))
def generate_data():
    update_rover_samples()
    for rover_data in rovers:
        print("thread finished...exiting")
        produce_data(rover_data)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    conf = {'bootstrap.servers': '127.0.0.2:9092'}
    producer = Producer(conf)

    delivered_records = 0

    create_topic()

    def ack(err, msg):
        global delivered_records
        """
        Message Delivered Successfully!!!
        """
        if err is not None:
            print("Failed to deliver message: {}".format(err))
        else:
            delivered_records += 1
            print("Produced record to topic {} partition [{}] @ offset {}"
                  .format(msg.topic(), msg.partition(), msg.offset()))


    generate_data()
```

Now I can call generate_data() 4 times and it will update it 4 times, but after the producer is done and called again, the script makes new data. I know I can just link it to a database, but I only have 1 object I need to update, so I was wondering if there is anything I can use with environment variables, or if there is any specific way of storing it that would work best.

pretty new to kafka so any advice would help!

Comment: Take a look at the *pickle* module

Comment: I would recommend sqlite3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good shell for opening, modifying, and writing out to a file from Python would be something like this. Here you can modify the file without overwriting the original.
You can modify this however you'd like to suit the structure of your saved object. Also, the ALL CAPS are just placeholders here.

```
replacedContent = ""
with open(FILE, 'r') as input_file:       
    for line in input_file.readlines():
        #File modification logic here
        if line.startswith(STRING_VARIABLE):
                updateLine = line.replace(line[16:], SOME_STRING + "\"\n")
        else:
            updateLine = line

        replacedContent = replacedContent + updateLine
    
    input_file.close()
    output_file = open(NEWFILE, "w")
    output_file.write(replacedContent)
    output_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about kafka, but If it is just a value you want to store and read, simply create a file with no extension (or .txt) and read / write it.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp

If you want to store more data in organized way, read about .json files.